# I am getting a "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." when using Cython with a Numpy program

Tags: python, cython

I am trying to build a library using Numpy and Cython. While compiling the .pyx file went smoothly, I can't test out the files in a test file.

It just says ", line 1, in 
import blank_cy #The name of the .pyd
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

I have tried looking at other similar problems but I still can't figure it out. Also, I am not sure what information I need on here so please ask. I'll just list off some things.

1. The .pyx file imports numpy as np and math and cimports numpy as np.
2. The compiling process does not produce any errors.
3. I renamed the file to match my import
4. Without imports it works fine.

Thank you so much.

Here's an example.

This would be the test.pyx

```
import numpy
cimport numpy

print("Hello World");
```

The setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx"),include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

The test file to import test.pyd

```
import test
```

Comment: You need to create a [mcve], otherwise is is hard to help. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388125/5769463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I renamed the file to match my import

Don't do this! This is your problem.

When it imports an extension named `my_module` Python looks for a function called `PyInit_my_module` (the function name is slightly different for Python 2, or if the module name has non-ascii characters, but the same basic idea applies) as the module initialisation function.

Since you've renamed your module the name of the initialisation function that Cython has created no longer matches and thus the whole thing breaks.

Just ensure that your pyx files have the module name that you ultimately want to use.

Comment: When I run the setup.py it creates a file named pizza_hut.cp38-win_amd64.pyd. I deleted the middle part, so don't do that? If I don't delete it, I have a different problem. It tells me that no module exist with that name. (Note: I changed the name to pizza_hut to avoid confusion with a native test module).

Comment: Deleting the `cp38-win_amd64` shouldn't stop the module import from working (but [that tag is there for good reasons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/) - there's no point to removing it). Renaming the first bit (`pizza_hut`) would break the import.

Comment: Oh, I meant I changed both .pyx file as well. So, it creates a file named pizza_hut